# Finding the Maximum element in a list with pattern matching and recursion F#

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

I'm trying to find the maximum element in a list without using List.Max for a school assignment using the below given template.

```
        let findMax l = 
        let rec helper(l,m) = failwith "Not implemented"

        match l with
        | [] -> failwith "Error -- empty list"
        | (x::xs) -> helper(xs,x)
```

The only solution to the problem I can think of, atm is

```
        let rec max_value1 l =
          match l with
          |[] -> failwith "Empty List"
          |[x] -> x
          |(x::y::xs) ->  if x<y then max_value1 (y::xs)
                else max_value1 (x::xs)

        max_value1 [1; 17; 3; 6; 1; 8; 3; 11; 6; 5; 9];;
```

Is there any way I can go from the function I built to one that uses the template? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the max value from a list with a function that takes two arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474382/how-do-i-get-the-max-value-from-a-list-with-a-function-that-takes-two-arguments)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your helper function should do the work, the outer function just validates that the list is not empty and if it's not, calls the helper, which should be something like this:

```
let rec helper (l,m) = 
    match (l, m) with
    | []   , m -> m
    | x::xs, m -> helper (xs, max m x)
```

Note, that you since you're matching against the last argument of the function you can remove it and use `function` instead of `match` `with`:

```
let rec helper = function
    | []   , m -> m
    | x::xs, m -> helper (xs, max m x)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
let findMax l = 
  let rec helper(l,m) =
    match l with
    | [] -> m
    | (x::xs) -> helper(xs, if (Some x > m) then Some x else m)
  helper (l,None)
```

Example:

```
[-2;-6;-1;-9;-56;-3] |> findMax  
val it : int option = Some -1
```

An empty list will return None.

Answer (score 3):

You could go for a tuple to pass both, or simply apply the helper function in your main match (instead of the empty list guard clause). I'm including the answer for someone who might find this question in the future and not have a clear answer.

```
let findMax l = 
   let rec walk maxValue = function
       | [] -> maxValue
       | (x::xs) -> walk (if x > maxValue then x else maxValue) xs
   match l with 
   | [] -> failwith "Empty list"
   | (head::tail) -> walk head tail

findMax [1; 12; 3; ] //12
```

Using fold:

```
let findMax l = l |> List.fold (fun maxValue x -> if x > maxValue then x else maxValue) (List.head l)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of what the exact rules of your assigment are but the max of a list is really just `List.reduce max`. So

```
let listMax : int list -> int = List.reduce max
```

You need the type annotation to please the typechecker.

```
let inline listMax xs = List.reduce max xs
```

also works and is generic so it works with e.g. floats and strings as well.